# Extract specific length numbers from a string

Tags: string, asp-classic

I need to be able to, with classic asp to extract specific length numbers from a string, such as 12 digit numbers, so I can insert them into separate rows into a table.

The location of the numbers in the string will be quite random, and there might be 1, there might be 50 12 digit numbers

A sample  of the string is:

> *1.       100001693263    Budrium Pty Ltd         $6,13059             $0.00                     -$6,13.59
>   2.       100000970265    Heriium Pty Ltd          $4,63.64             $0.00                     -$4,33.64
>   3.       100001730295    SURFE LOCKSMITHS              $6987.60           $52,32.00           -$17,5.60*

which has 3 of course.

Can someone help? I googled it quite a bit but didn't find anything specific enough. I'm also not fussed if I can get code where it just dumps the 3 numbers for example in its own string separated by commas or something like that.

Comment: You can use a regular expression for this.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression which return any group of 12 digit characters (0-9): `(\d{12})`

Try this code:

```
text = "100001693263 Budrium Pty Ltd $6,13059 $0.00 -$6,13.59 2. 100000970265 Heriium Pty Ltd $4,63.64 $0.00 -$4,33.64 3. 100001730295 SURFE LOCKSMITHS $6987.60 $52,32.00 -$17,5.60"

Set regex = New RegExp
regex.Global = true
regex.Pattern = "(\d{12})"

Set matches = regex.Execute(text)
 
For each match in matches
   Response.Write(match.Value & "<br />")
Next
```

Notes:

- [Global Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdte5kwf(v=VS.85).aspx):

  > Sets or returns a Boolean value that indicates if a pattern should match all occurrences in an entire search string or just the first one.

Comment: You sir, are awesome! perfect!

ps. I didn't downvote

Comment: Not my downvote, but there is no real explanation how the code works, probably that's the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Maybe but there's not a lot to explain here. I'll add some explanation later. @Shadow Wizard

Comment: I know hence I upvoted, maybe just explain more clearly the the regex is doing.